# Reputation of users who closed the question doesn't show up on Mouse Over

Tags: feature-request, reputation, closed-questions

I noticed a behavior that when we hover over the usernames (users) who closed a question, their reputation doesn't show under the mouse like in comments. The reputation should also show under these usernames. Here is an animation to simply explain it:

[image]

Comment: True...but *does it matter*?

Comment: @Paulie_D I think it matters. I was trying to see the users rep but found this bug :)   . Also if it does not matter then there is no purpose to show rep on comments too.

Comment: @BlackThunder and why do you assume it is a bug?  How do you know the behavior you are expecting is how the system was designed?  This question might be a feature request to include this information

Comment: @psubsee2003 The fact that rep shows on comments but doesn't show on users closed the question clearly tells that it is a bug.

Comment: @BlackThunder But that's *not* a comment. That is a close message

Comment: @astonearachnid What are not comments?

Comment: @BlackThunder The close message is a close message, not a comment.

Comment: But the rep should also show on the close message. However should I replace bug with feature-request?

Comment: Then it should be a [feature-request], not a [bug]. Not showing it is current behavior.